# A list type label in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I was trying to add to a pod a list of values inside one key as a label, thing is it doesn't really work, when I try to do `kubectl edit po/sektor -o yaml` 
(sektor is pod name) and then in labels section I edited the "abilities" label like this:

```
  labels:
    abilities:
        - ability1: fire
        - ability2: teleport
        - ability3: rocekts
```

but when I try to save it shows me the following error:
Invalid value: "The edited file failed validation": ValidationError(Pod.metadata.labels.abilities): invalid type for io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta.labels: got "array", expected "string"

So I see that I need to change the type of that label somehow but I can't figure out how.

If it's possible, anyone knows how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible because of the definition of `Labels`. According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) `Labels` are key/value pairs. What you could do there tho, would be to have something like this:

```
labels:
  ability-fire: true
  ability-teleport: true
  ability-rockets: true
```

With this way you can easily create [Selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors) for your other Resources like `Services`.

Comment: Nit: You'd need to quote `true`, since label values are only strings.